# Converting an expression to a trigonometric form

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have this expression to convert in trig form:
$z=-\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+ i\sin\frac{\pi}{7}$

Tried to move the minus sine inside the $\cos$ function, but that just wouldn't work,
then with the help of $\sin x=\cos(90-x))$ tried to change the expression to:
$$
z=-\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}+i\cos\frac{5\pi}{14}
$$

Here I moved the minus sine inside the sine function since it's allowed:
$$
z=\sin\dfrac{-5\pi}{14}+i\cos\frac{5\pi}{14}
$$

Again using $\cos x=\sin(90-x))$ to convert the real part to $\cos$: 
$$
\sin\frac{-5\pi}{14}=\cos\left(90+\frac{5\pi}{14}\right)
$$

$$
\sin\frac{-5\pi}{14}=\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)
$$

and the imaginary part to:
$$
\cos\frac{5\pi}{14}=\sin\left(90-\frac{5\pi}{14}\right)
$$

$$
\cos\frac{5\pi}{14}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)
$$

now I would get different angles for sine and cosine, which I think doesn't fit the general trig form:
$z=r(\cos x+i\sin x)$

I would really appreciate the help for this problem!

Comment: I very strongly recommend you do **NOT** mix degrees and radians in the same sentence. Basically, *forget about degrees when you're doing this!* Technically speaking, you actually wrote several false statements here. Without the explicitly shown degree symbol, all numbers are interpreted as radian measure when used in trig functions. So by writing  "$\sin x=\cos(90-x)$" you said that $\sin$ of $x$ is equal to $\cos$ of $90$ radians minus $x$. I know you didn't mean that, but you said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is write this expression in the form $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ with the same value of $\theta$ and without the minus sign in front of the cosine. Note that we have the following identities:
$$\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin\alpha.$$
Therefore:
$$z=-\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+ i\sin\frac{\pi}{7}=\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{7}\right)+ i\sin\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{7}\right)=\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+ i\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}.$$

**EDIT.** Of course, in fact you need to write it in the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. But after performing the step explained above, it's quite clear that $r=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$r(\cos y+i\sin y)=-\cos\dfrac\pi7+i\sin\dfrac\pi7,$$ where $r>0,y$ are real

Equate the real & the imaginary parts

to find $\dfrac{r\sin y}{r\cos y}=-\tan\dfrac\pi7=\tan\left(-\dfrac\pi7\right)$

using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)

$\implies y=\pi+\left(-\dfrac\pi7\right)$

Square & add the real & the imaginary parts to find $r=1$

Comment: Why would I want to find tan(y), I have the angles from the formulas: cos(pi-x)=-cosx and sin(pi-x)=+sinx, a little explanation please!

Comment: @L.B, This is a general solution. How can we identify $\pi-x$ w/o observation?

Comment: For my question will this answer be correct: z=cos$\frac{6pi}{7}+isin\frac{6pi}{7}$

Comment: @L.B, Have u understood my method?

Comment: I'm not understanding your method.I'm thinking if we change the sign for cos, and with that the angle for both functions sine and cosine, I would have the standard form, as for equating the real and imaginary part, I'm confused, why are we doing that, what's the purpose.

Comment: @L.B, Please find the updated answer

Comment: I don't understand the equating part, how do you do that?

Comment: @L.B, If $$x+iy=a+ib,$$ $$x=a,y=b$$

Comment: So now we have cosy=-cos(pi/7) and siny=sin(pi/7), is this equal to y=pi/7 and y=-pi/7

Comment: @L.B, Clearly, none of them, but $$y=\pi-\dfrac\pi7$$

Comment: OK, so after we have found the y, what's the next step?

Comment: @L.B, So, we have identified $r,y$